# Merging two pandas dataframes and keep available value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two datafames (A and B) on a key say X, so that if there is a common column K (assume we dont know the name of this column) with same name in both dataframes then we should keep values where it is present

Example for row 1: if A has value in K (and not B) then keep A's value, but for row 2: if B has value in K (and not A) then keep that value. 
If present in both then keep anyone.

We dont know the column name. So pls don’t mark it as already solved with pd.merge and then apply with column names.  See picture for explanation ( there might be 50 columns like Name here)

[image: Like this]

Comment: Some concrete example input and output would be helpful here

Comment: Added a link for better example

Comment: you can use `pd.merge()` check its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Use: pd.merge(df1, df2, all.x=True) but this is a duplicated question and have been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499709/merge-dataframes-based-on-common-columns-but-keeping-all-rows-from-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: @Mack123456 pd.merge(df1, df2, all.x=True) doesn't work, and the questions you posted refer to R code not Python code

Comment: Agreed, however code by @Massifox solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). See this example:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                     'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', None]} , 
                    columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name'])

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                     'first_name': [None, 'Brian', 'Bran', 'Bryce', 'Betty']}, 
                    columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name'])
```

Using `pd.merge()` do the *outer join* on 'subject_id':

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on='subject_id', how='outer')
```

and you get:

```
subject_id first_name_x first_name_y
0          1         Alex          NaN
1          2          Amy          NaN
2          3        Allen          NaN
3          4        Alice         None
4          5         None        Brian
5          6          NaN         Bran
6          7          NaN        Bryce
7          8          NaN        Betty
```

You can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) to conditionally assign a value from the _x and _y columns:

```
df_merge['first_name'] = df_merge['first_name_x'].where(df_merge['first_name_x'].notnull(), df_merge['first_name_y'])
```

Using `.drop()` method to delete *_x* and *_y* columns:

```
df_res = df_merge.drop(['first_name_x', 'first_name_y'], axis=1)
```

And get the result you are looking for:

```
print(df_res)
  subject_id first_name
0          1       Alex
1          2        Amy
2          3      Allen
3          4      Alice
4          5      Brian
5          6       Bran
6          7      Bryce
7          8      Betty
```

If you don't know the name of the columns that will be generated from the merge, you can use this code:

```
suffixes = ('__x', '__y')
df_merge = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on='subject_id', how='outer', suffixes=suffixes)

drop_cols = []
for col in df_merge.columns:
    if col.endswith(suffixes[0]):
        new_col = col[:-len(suffixes[0])]
        df_merge[new_col] = df_merge[col].where(df_merge[col].notnull(), df_merge[new_col + suffixes[1]])
        drop_cols.extend([col, new_col + suffixes[1]])

df_merge.drop(columns=drop_cols, inplace=True)
```

**Note**: For a more detailed explanation you can refer to the official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), while [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/) you will find many examples.

Comment: Only catch is, I don’t know the column names (Name here).. there could be 500 columns which are in both fd)

Comment: Ok @SumitSingh, I updated my answer and added the code to answer also your last question. If that's what you needed mark my answer as best, thanks a lot :)

Comment: seems like i dont have much reputation - Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.